# Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

I have implemented `CustomAlertDialogBuilder` but I am getting the following warning:

> The object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member

Below is my code:

```
override fun onEditClick(item: Question) {
    CustomAlertDialogBuilder(context).setCancelable(true)

    CustomAlertDialogBuilder(context).addMessage(R.string.chat_message).setPositiveButton(R.string.chat,

        object : CustomAlertDialogBuilder.OnItemDialogClickListener {
            override fun onClick(dialog: CustomAlertDialogBuilder.CustomDialogInterface) {
                val intent = Intent(context, ChatActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("OK", null).build()?.show()
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the error:

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcdOD.jpg)

Below `CustomDialogBuilder.OnItemDialogClickListener` interface:

```
interface OnItemDialogClickListener {
    fun onClick(dialog: CustomDialogInterface)
    fun onClick(arg0: CustomAlertDialogBuilder, arg1: Int)
}
```

Comment: some functions of `CustomAlertDialogBuilder.OnItemDialogClickListener` interface are not implemented, take a look what other functions you should implement besides `onClick`

Comment: add `arg1:Int` as the second param of overridden `onClick` function.

Comment: @Sergey still error I have added

Comment: @Sergey do you have other suggestion as well

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: could you please add code of `CustomAlertDialogBuilder.OnItemDialogClickListener`

Comment: @Sergey what do you mean I already added

Comment: The code of the interface declaration.

Comment: What is `CustomAlertDialogBuilder`? is it the class you created or it is from some library?

Comment: @Sergey it is already implemented here do you have other suggestion

Comment: I asked about declaration, not implementation

Comment: @Sergey they have used cicerone I dont know

Comment: I see that you posted code of implementation. But I need to look at the declaration of `CustomAlertDialogBuilder.OnItemDialogClickListener` interface.

Comment: @Sergey I have added already can you check it thanks

Comment: This is helpful. Please check my answer. Basically you need to implement two methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `arg1:Int` as the second param of overridden `onClick` function and make type of first parameter as `CustomAlertDialogBuilder`, e.g.:

```
override fun onEditClick(item: Question) {
    CustomAlertDialogBuilder(context).setCancelable(true)

    CustomAlertDialogBuilder(context).addMessage(R.string.chat_message).setPositiveButton(R.string.chat,

    object : CustomAlertDialogBuilder.OnItemDialogClickListener {
        override fun onClick(dialog: CustomAlertDialogBuilder, arg1: Int) {
            val intent = Intent(context, ChatActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        override fun onClick(dialog: CustomDialogInterface) {
            // ...
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("OK", null).build()?.show()
}
```

Also check if other methods of `CustomAlertDialogBuilder.OnItemDialogClickListener` are implemented.

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: stll the same issue

Comment: did you implement two methods as in my answer?

Comment: ok, so the error is disappeared? you need to check why the app is crashing. Just check logs.

Comment: I have a edit text when user clicks it will show pop dialog there two chat and okay when user clicks chat it should open chat activity I wanted to implement but it is giving that error I have changed as you told code just messup thats why I think I have to think other method

Comment: There is no other method. You have the `CustomAlertDialogBuilder.OnItemDialogClickListener` interface with two abstract methods which you should implement.

Comment: My suggestion is in my answer. Did it help you to get rid of the error? If app crashes check logs and determine the location of the error. Or you can create another question on StackOverflow.